# Using the same table on SELECT and WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

#### Simple case

I have a simple table where one column is the PK of another element of the same table, as follows:

```
    id     |  something   | parent_id
___________|______________|____________
     1     |   colors     |  null
     2     |   red        |  1
     3     |   green      |  1
     4     |   blue       |  1
    ...    |   ...        | ...
```

#### Task

I wanted to get all elements that have the `parent_id` of the element that matches a condition.
Let's suppose the parent element should have `something='colors'`

#### Expected Result

```
    id     |  something   | parent_id
___________|______________|____________
     2     |   red        |  1
     3     |   green      |  1
     4     |   blue       |  1
```

---

After looking around on StackOverflow I have tried:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 
   parent_id=(SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE something='colors')
```

and also:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table as t1 WHERE
   t1.parent_id=(SELECT id FROM my_table as t2 WHERE t2.something='colors')
```

but I get this error:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax

**The reason was a missing `;` on the previous file that was being merged before mine. The above queries do work**...

---

This is not my field and I know that a "*solution*"(**?**) (*used by others in the project*) could be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 
    parent_id=(SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM my_table) AS t1 WHERE something='colors')
```

but I don't really like this

---

Thanks anyone for the help.
I know we should `LIMIT 1` or use `IN` to prevent errors, I was trying to simplify the sintax as most as I could.

Comment: will you share also the other part of the error. You have for sure more than this

Comment: @LelioFaieta unfortunately it's all I can read

Comment: you can use CTE to achieve this.

Comment: @beegotsy . . . Your query looks fine.  I suspect you have an issue with your table name, or you are really trying to do an `update` or `delete`, or you have a bad character in your query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff after replying the error even with the other guys queries I checked the file that was being merged before mine and the last query was without the final ;
Problem solved... Thank you for the help, I don't delete the question if anyone is searching for stupid errors, always helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it with a simple JOIN:

```
SELECT T1.* FROM my_table AS T1 
JOIN my_table AS T2 ON T1.parent_id = T2.id
WHERE T2.something='colors';
```

This technique is known as a SELF JOIN. [Here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

use exists

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table_name t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_name t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.parent_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.id = t.parent_id AND t1.something = 'colors');
```